# Get multiple secrets from one Credential Store in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, credentials

For my pipeline, I want to keep the subscription ID, tenant ID, client ID, and password all out of source control, and keep all of those in a single credential store in Jenkins.  It seems that there is not a $class that matches this for withCredentials, but I just want to use credentials() in the environment anyways.  Am I mistaken that the credentials('file') method reads as a single value, or is there a way to format that file such that Jenkins will parse it and make each secret available?

```
//Jenkinsfile (Declarative Pipeline)
pipeline {
    agent { label 'AZcli' }

    environment {
        SECRETS_FILE = credentials('AZJenkinsSecretsFile')
    }
```

Then what?

Let's say this is the AZJenkinsSecretsFile.txt that I've uploaded.

```
subscription=xxxx-xxx-xx-xx-x
tenant=xxx-xxx-xxx-xx
client=xxx-xxxx-xxx
password=password
```

Comment: You can also use `string` or a third party source such as Vault for this.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a `Secretfile` you will be given a Path to a temporary file with the secret content. Secret files are intended to be passed as a whole file. For example, you can have your `kubeconfigs` file as a `Secretfile` and then pass it directly to `kubectl` like `kubectl --kubeconfig $SECRET_CONFIG`.

If you want to export each line in the secret file as a variable, it's doable. But when you start using them in your `shell` steps their values will be exposed in the logs. In order to use them, you can use something like below.

```bash
sh """
  source $SECRETS_FILE
  echo "\$subscription"
  echo "\$tenant"
"""
```

Comment: Alright, well, I tried using the Secret Text option instead, and passed the -var flag arguments (multiple in one text) to terraform apply.  Unfortunately, it seems that it's trying to anticipate what's a secret and what isn't and it's exposing all the secrets except the last one in console.  Do you know how to get it to treat the entire Secret Text as a secret?  Thank you for your help.